# How to resize an input box on focus with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have an input box, which is quite small when it's loaded and I want it to resize to become bigger when the user clicks on it (with CSS).

The CSS code I have is:

```
input.tagInputField {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 border: none;
 background-color: #fff;
 width: 2em;
 color: #000;
 font-size: 14px;
}

input.tagInputField:focus {
 width: 50px;
}
```

But it's not working... no response... Any ideas?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

the html code (sorry for the pic, it was the fastest to get it this way)

[image]

Comment: what code are you using to call the click event?

Comment: @webeno, what click event? This is CSS only. OP, can you show your HTML too please because it works fine for me : http://jsfiddle.net/v4r2cag4/

Comment: the input form is actually generated through the http://ioncache.github.io/Tag-Handler/ code, so it's not there when the page loads, however it does show up. the user simply clicks on that input form that's generated and the styles from CSS apply fine to it, it's just that i can't find how to change its width...

Comment: @putvande well, i might have missed CSS classes, but what would otherwise make the element change style then on click...?

Comment: The `:focus` bit in the CSS, which means that when the the `input` gets the focus ;)

Comment: @webeno - It doesn't have anything to do with a click.  It has to do with when the element gains focus.  This is done with a pseudo-selector in CSS (the `:focus` pseudo in the above code).  In JavaScript, it would be either the attribute `onfocus="someFunction()"` or `addEventListener('focus', function() { /* some code here */ }`

Comment: @putvande you got me, what was i thinking...? :)

Comment: It works! http://jsfiddle.net/06t09fyv/ You need to show us that's not working...

Comment: posted the code, @putvande

Comment: OP: are you sure the styling doesn't get overwritten by something else?

Comment: Are you sure: 1. that some other file is not overriding it, 2. that 50px is bigger than `2em`? EMs are turned into pixel sizes based on a number of factors.

Comment: @putvande spoton! in fact adding !important; helped. if you post the answer, i'll be happy to accept it:)

Answer (score 1):

It worked. Some other styles were overriding this one, so as per @putvande suggestion I checked that and added `!important`

```
input.tagInputField:focus {
 width: 50px !important;
}
```